# ASP.NET and jQuery - submitting forms from a modal box?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, modal-dialog

I have an ASP.NET web site with master/content pages. On the master page, there is a link to log-in and that brings up a modal jQuery form. How can I make sure that the info that is submitted on this form (which is just a DIV in my master page) is handled by a particular postback event?

Keep in mind that the modal can be submitted from any number of pages and I want to make sure that when the modal is submitted, the postback event of the *content* page is ignored while the postback of the *master page* handles the form.

Answer (score 0):

if you leave the postback address blank (in html) it will post to the same page. if you can't do this, try passing in a variable with the page's address.

Comment: If it posts to the same page that means that the content page will pick it up - I need the master page to pick it up

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent your Content page from detecting that a postback has happened.  The way MasterPages/Content Pages work is that the MasterPage is applied to the Content page after `OnPreInit` at that point the MasterPage is accessibly from the Content page.  However, if you define the button handler in your MasterPage

```
<asp:Button ... OnClick='myHandler'>
```

you can do any processing from within the MasterPage's code-behind.

```
protected void myHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...handle button click...}
```

But, that handler will be triggered after the Content page and Master Page has fired all events before the `OnLoadComplete()` page method

Comment: In Summary - In the ASP.Net Page LifeCycle the MasterPage and ContentPage are not independent and cannot be separated